# Collections as decorators in C#

Tags: c#, collections, decorator

We've been hit with a pretty "obvious" problem while designing a collections infrastructure: suppose you need to implement many (sub)types of collections. One of the aspects is **storage-related**: *list*, *array* etc, while the other is **behavior-related**: *ordered*, *remove only*, *observable* (the one that fires an event upon every change) etc.

Obviously (again), the requirement maps directly to the well-known *Decorator* design pattern (*list*, *array*), where the storage-related aspect will be decorated by multiple behavioral (*ordered*, *observable* etc).

It would be great to know about something similar that had been already implemented by someone. Hence, if possible - please recommend/refer to any well-maintained third-party library that would meet the requirements, mentioned above.

Thanks so far :)

Comment: The only library I have ever come across that did this was the old C++ Borland International Data Structures (BIDS) library.  Would also be interested in any C# libraries in this style.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood something:

*Decorators* are used to modify and add behaviour primarily *at runtime*. But the properties of collections that you cited need to be available *at compile time*. A decorator is completely unsuited to add more methods to an existing class.

While it is possible to decompose these traits of collections into interfaces (and indeed has been done <sup>1)</sup>), this isn’t really what a decorator is about: a decorator wraps an existing class implementing the same interface. For collections, inheritance will make more sense (or may indeed be required) instead of composition.

---

<sup>1)</sup> A few years, I started developing my own such library, [**Containers.NET**](http://madrat.net/projects/containers/) but since preliminary benchmarks showed just how much faster the native .NET containers were, even though Containers.NET did not have any added overhead, I stopped the project before it got very far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133176/collections-as-decorators-pseudo-code-implementation-proposal - Here I've asked more general question (hope it's okay). 

I read your point. Just wanted to take the Decorator idea one step further, i.e. enrich the behavior in runtime and interface both in compile-time and runtime. Why compile time? Because I want to instantiate an Observable, Ordered, ReadOnly, ThreadSafe List instance. And be able to call all the methods like "add/remove()", "sort() and "notifyChange()", for example.

Comment: @BreakPhreak: I’ve read your other question, that’s how I came here. I still think you’re basically operating on a misconception. Or otherwise, I don’t understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: PS: maybe someone took your idea further or developed his/her own alternative. Would be interesting to know that such a product exists.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase. Term-less-wise, I'd like to use some collections framework, where aspects can be dynamically constructed into any possible combination (in contrary to OrderedReadOnlyThreadSafeList, for example, I would like to have Ordered, ReadOnly ThreadSafe and List implemented separately, but combineable in compile/run time). Does my goal sound better this time?